# adding text to a line in a file

Tags: python, string, file, text

I have a text file that contains a number, a space, and a name.
For example:
12 chicken
1 bread
24 forest

I'm pretty new to python but I wonder if there is a method to add text to that list so it can became like:

list of goodies
number 12 of chicken for me
number 1 of bread for me

I write the following code but I still have problem to add the "of" in the middle of the line.

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(['./lista.txt'], inplace=True):
    if fileinput.filelineno() == 1:
         sys.stdout.write('list of goodies{l} \n'.format(l=line)) 

    sys.stdout.write( '{0}{1}{2}'.format('number', line.rstrip('\n'), 'for me \n'))
```

And I've not clearly understand the use of .format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
import fileinput
import sys

print 'list of goodies'
for line in fileinput.input(['./lista.txt'], inplace=True):
    number, item = line.rstrip().split(' ', 1) # strip new line from right, split on first space
    print 'number {0} of {1} for me'.format(number, item)
```

Basically, format takes a number of string arguments which it then inserts in the string you call it for in place of the identifiers {0},{1},... where the number represents it's position in the argument list. If you supply a named argument (l=line), it will be inserted into the string where {argname} pops up. E.g:

```
print '{0}.{0}-{1}:{test}'.format('first','second', test='third')
```

will print

```
first.first-second:third
```

Comment: but this doesn't work if I have a compound word like:
   peanut butter

Comment: You're right about that. line.split(' ', 1) should do it. Fixing my answer.

Comment: i don't understand why i find for me in the next line

Comment: Oh yeah, that's because when reading each line you get the newline character \n at the end of each line, which, when printed, will make the print statement break lines when outputting. You need to do a line.rstrip() first, which will remove all whitespace characters from the right side of the string (e.g. 'hi\n   \n'.rstrip() becomes 'hi').

Answer (score 0):

To turn "12 chicken" into "12 of chicken", you'll need to `split` the line into words and then `join` them back together with " of " in the middle. For example:

```
s = '12 chicken'
print(s.split())
print(" of ".join(s.split()))
```

produces this:

```
['12', 'chicken']
12 of chicken
```

Apply this to `line` in your loop.

**Further explanation:** I'll try to help you understand `format()` better. The `'{0}{1}{2}'` means take the first, second, and third arguments to `format()` and concatenate them. For example, in the expression `'{0}{1}{2}'.format('number', line.rstrip('\n'), 'for me \n')`:

- `{0}` corresponds to `'number'`
- `{1}` corresponds to `line.rstrip('\n')` (such as `"12 chicken"`)
- `{2}` corresponds to `'for me \n'`

To replace `"12 chicken"` with `"12 of chicken"`, you'll need to substitute `line.rstrip('\n')` for `s` in `" of ".join(s.split())`, producing `" of ".join(line.rstrip('\n').split())`.

Comment: sys.stdout.write( '{0}{1}{2} 3}'.format('number','of'.join(line.split()),line.rstrip('\n'), 'for me \n'))

I get "number12ofchicken12 chickenfor me"

Comment: In your comment, it appears that `{0}` is `'number'`, `{1}` is `'of'.join(line.split())`, and `{2}` is `line.rstrip('\n')`. You need to apply the `split` and `join` operations to `line.rstrip('\n')` itself: `'of'.join(line.rstrip().split())`

Comment: it worked and i own you a lot. I got the error.even if i don't understand why i didn't have to give a parameter to line.rstrip().

Comment: A lot of methods in Python do something useful even if an argument is left out. For example, no argument on `str.rstrip()` causes it to strip whitespace. Likewise, no argument on `str.split()` causes it to split at whitespace.